# Use $localize in Angular 10 (with ivy) Library

Tags: angular, localization

I've build a local angular library with angular@10 using ivy and i want to use the new $localize string template functionality.

`` public test = $localize `:@@test:Test`; ``

Within a normal app i would enable this by adding `@import '@angular/loclize/init';` to the polyfill.ts, but within a library there are no polyfills.

When i try to build the library its fails, so i tried to import the `@angular/localize/src/localize` to the file in which i used the $localize. After doing that the build is running. But if i use the library within a app it says:

`Can't resolve '@angular/localize/src/localize'`

Has anyone a way to solve that? Maybe i am using the wrong approach.

Comment: The lib was failing not because the import of `@angular/localize/src/localize` was missing. The lib fails because of other reasons. Could you please provide the error when trying to build the lib? Also to use `$localize` for dynamic translation, you don't need: `import {$localize} from "@angular/localize/src/localize"`.

Comment: I will try to reproduce it in the next days. I aware, that you usually not have to import localize, but as i wrote within the library is the polyfill missing, which declares $localize.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare function $localize(messageParts: TemplateStringsArray, ...expressions: readonly any[]): string;
```

add this line to file next to the src file of the library
and you can use it in the same way like you use it in app and this is work fine.

Comment: Which file do you mean by "src file", the module, the public-api?

Comment: in projects/{name_of_library} . next to the src folder